# How to verify 2 fingerprint templates

Tags: java, match, matching, fingerprint, ansi

I am trying the sourceafis library, to check fingerprints, I would like to go deeper and I would like to find documentation or code, where it is explained how to do match two templates, it does not matter if it is ISO or ANSI, but I am not interested in seeing the algorithm Which verifies the minutiae (X, Y, T) and how the result is obtained

Comment: Have you looked into their [documentation](https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/javadoc/)? You could find references to the method's name, and then search for it (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_scalar_quantization), for example).

Comment: I use the api, maybe my English is not very good. So to speak, I want to develop the verificative on my own, or develop my own function

Comment: I thought you wanted the name of the method they use so you could search for it and implement such a method yourself - your best bet would probably search their [code repositories](https://sourceforge.net/p/sourceafis/code/ci/default/tree/).